# VBA for Excel - Setting a range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question about set range. There is something that I am trying and it's not working. Let's say I have range r, for example I wrote:

```
set r = range("a1")
```

But this range is valid for the active worksheet, for example if I am on worksheet1 and I write r.value = 1 then it will change the value of that cell on the active worksheet. Now I want to change the value of that specific range on another worksheet. So I write

```
worksheets("specificworksheet").r.value =1
```

But when I write this, it says Object doesn't support this propert or method. why is that? How can i assign a range (that was already set) for another worksheet? In this case writing

```
worksheets("specificworksheet").range("a1").value=1
```

would solve my problem, however, somethimes I have more complicated range, for example if I assinged a cell to r, where I used cells.find(...). 
Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Kudos for not defaulting to `Select` and `Activate` upon realising that unqualified `Range` calls implicitly refer to the active sheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use Address:

```
worksheets("specificworksheet").range(r.Address).value=1
```

Answer (score 8):

When you do:

```
Set r = Range("A1")
```

What you're *really* doing is this:

```
Dim r As Variant
Set r = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
```

So declare all your variables, and **always** specify `Option Explicit` at the top of every module - that way VBA will refuse to compile code that uses undeclared variables (or typos). And declare your variables with an explicit type:

```
Dim r As Range
```

A `Range` object knows about its `Parent`, which is the worksheet it belongs to; that's why, as you noted, *this range is valid for the active worksheet*. And it remains on that sheet even if you activate another sheet (which you wouldn't need to do 99.999% of the time anyway).

That's why you can't do this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet42").r.Value = 1
```

Because `r` isn't a member of the `Worksheet` object - it's a local object variable that points to a very specific address on a very specific worksheet. Now, when you do `Worksheets("Sheet42")`, you're really accessing the default property of the `Worksheets` collection class, which is its `Item` property:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = Worksheets.Item("Sheet42")
```

And the `Worksheets` collection's `Item` property returns an `Object`, which means any member call you add after that is going to be late-bound / resolved at run-time:

```
Dim obj As Object
Set obj = Worksheets.Item("Sheet42")
obj.AnythingYouWantHereWillCompileAnyway
```

At run-time, VBA queries the object's interface to look for `AnythingYouWantHereWillCompileAnyway`, and doesn't find that member - and that's how you get a run-time error 438 - "object doesn't support this property or method".

You can move that type-safety back to compile-time (instead of run-time) by working with early-bound calls, i.e. work with the `Worksheet` interface/class instead of `Object`:

```
Dim obj As Worksheet
Set obj = Worksheets.Item("Sheet42")
obj.AnythingYouWantHereWillCompileAnyway 'nope. that won't compile anymore.
```

---

When you ask *how can I assign a range (that was already set) for another worksheet?*, you assume a `Range` object is nothing more than an address - and that assumption is wrong.

A `Range` is *much* more than just an address. If it were just an address, then it would be a string literal, not an object.

If you want a variable that represents an address, you can do that with a `String` variable:

```
Dim a As String
a = "A1"

Dim r1 As Range
Set r1 = Sheet1.Range(a)

Dim r2 As Range
Set r2 = Sheet2.Range(a)
```

Comment: @Downvoter I'd love to improve this answer. Mind telling me what's wrong with it?

Comment: Again, much better explanation and resolution.  I thought about adding the string approach but then got busy, just came back but I will leave as is and hope that the OP changes to yours.

Comment: Edited to include a more complete explanation of OP's runtime error 438.

Comment: I suppose @Downvoter wanted a quick "try this" copy-pasta answer - go ahead and downvote all my answers then, because I don't do that.

Comment: oooooh oooooh {*waves hands in the air frantically*}, I do that. 8P And that is why you have three upvotes to my two, currently

Comment: And why this should be the accepted answer. @mathstackuser123

Comment: @ScottCraner eh, I didn't mean to "attack" your perfectly valid answer - I'm just puzzled with how some people spend their (down)votes sometimes. Cheers!

Comment: no offense was taken, I stated the above, extremely sarcastically.  I know I do just enough, and that sometimes my answers are lacking in detail.  I was trying to be funny.  Text just does not convey humor properly.

Comment: Lovely. Thank you. I learned something from this question thanks to your answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

use `With-End With` syntax, and precede every `Range()` (and `Cells()`) specifications by a dot

```
With Worksheets("specificworksheet")
    .Range("a1").Value = 1
    .Range("B3:C5").Value = 2
End With
```

Comment: Downvoter I'd love to improve this answer. Mind telling me what's wrong with it? (hope @Mat'sMag won't mind my stealing his beautiful phrase)