# Looping through a list of country codes, error with Range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that will allow me to test the payment ability of a person based on his/her country of residence.

I have a list of country codes (rows "S73:S128"), examples being "SE" for Sweden, "UK" for United Kingdom, etc. I also have a list of average income for all the countries (rows "T73:T128").

The macro is supposed to edit a worksheet ("Calculator") that calculates payment ability and then copy the results into another worksheet ("Results"). For each country there are three scenarios: The person lives alone (O38 = 1, O39 = 0 in code below), the person shares his/her household with another adult (O38 = 2, O39 = 0 in code below) or the person lives with both another adult and a child (O38 = 2 and O39 = 1).

I thought the simplest way to do this would be a for-loop.

It's supposed to go through these steps:

1. Activate the calculator worksheet
2. Set Adults in household (O38) to 1.
3. Set children in household (O39) to 0.
4. Change value of Country Code cell (O9) to country code of current iteration (i.e. iterate through the range S73:S128)
5. Copy the country code from O9
6. Activate Results sheet
7. Paste the copied country code into the first empty cell in column A

... then proceeding to enter income of current iteration into cell O23, copying the payment ability output (N52) into the first empty cell in column B of the Results sheet, etc...

Here's my non-working code:

```
Sub LoopThroughCountries()

Dim CountryCode As Range
Dim CountryIncome As Range
Dim i As Long

Set CountryCode = Range("S73:S128")
Set CountryIncome = Range("T73:T128")

For i = 1 To CountryCode.Rows.Count
Worksheets("Calculator").Activate
Range("O38").Value = 1
Range("O39").Value = 0
Range("O9").Value = Range("CountryCode" & i)
Range("O9").Copy
Worksheets("Results").Activate
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Calculator").Activate
Range("O23").Value = Range("CountryIncome" & i)
Range("N52").Copy 'N52 is the payment ability output cell
Worksheets("Results").Activate
Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Pastes payment ability of scenario 1
Worksheets("Calculator").Activate
Range("O38").Value = 2
Range("N52").Copy
Worksheets("Results").Activate
Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Pastes payment ability of scenario 2
Worksheets("Calculator").Activate
Range("O39").Value = 1
Range("N52").Copy
Worksheets("Results").Activate
Range("D1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Pastes payment ability of scenario 3

Next i
End sub
```

The first line to fail is this:

```
Range("O9").Value = Range("CountryCode" & i)
```

Gives me the error: "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed"

What am I missing here? I've tried to search for how to use Range in VBA. I thought "Range("CountryCode" & i)" would basically give me the value of the ith iteration of the CountryCode-range. Is the line incomplete?

Comment: PLeeeease get rid of all those `Activate` and unqualified `Range`s ! That is unefficient and unreadable.

Comment: I agree... Right now I'm just trying to get it to work (it's the first thing I ever do in vba for excel), I'll focus on making it less ugly and inefficient later on.

Comment: All your calls to range are implicit, you don't specify which worksheet you are working on, probably not the error but something to keep in mind. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42812889/10223558

Comment: @Balthazar I definitely would cleanup and reengineer FIRST. Much easier to debug afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CountryCode` is already a range so, unless you have defined named ranges CountryCode1, CountryCode2, `Range("CountryCode" & i)` won't work.

`CountryCode.Cells(i, 1)` will refer to the i = 1st, 2nd, etc., row in the column defined as CountryCode.

Comment: Thank you, that's it! Made the same change to the CountryIncome part as well. There are issues with the paste parts of my code as well, will get to work on that now. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Andy G. That's really neat. I learned something new today!! Thanks. Balthazar, feel free to come back with new question at SO. Good you provide a trial code!!

Answer (score 1):

This might be a start for you.

You can build range as:

```
Range("S73:S128") -> Range(Cells(S73), Cells(S128)) -> 
Range(Cells(row number, column number), Cells(row number, column number)) -> 
Range(Cells(73, 19), Cells(128, 19))
```

Since you want to loop through the columns with variable "`i`", you denote the rows as `i` instead

So your code needs some modifications:
`For i = 1 To CountryCode.Rows.Count` -> `For i = 73 To CountryCode.Rows.Count` you can go from row 73 to last row if you want

```
Range("O9").Value = Range(Cells(i, 19), Cells(i, 19)).value
```